# Creating a custom tab in configuration with text field, and when updating a product "the word" will append with product name. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I am creating a small module. In which I have built my own tab in System- Configuration, Name "ZARA" which consists of a textbox. I can enter words in the textbox and save the configuration.

Now my problem is, I want that the module should append the word entered in the configuration to the product name through a so-called observer whenever a product is saved.

for example, I entered "Test" as a test word in the configuration. I then open a product in the backend in product management, which is called "RedShirt". When I save this now, it's called "RedShirtTest". If I save it again, it's called "RedShirtTestTest". Thank you in advance if anybody can clear my issue. I'm totally new to Magento. Please answer regarding Magento 1.9.

Comment: Please let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your module. If you want to use this only in backend change `global` node to `adminhtml` ...

> app/code/community/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
    ...
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <my_module_append_text>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>addText</method>
               </my_module_append_text>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

> app/code/community/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function addText(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getData('product');
        $text = Mage::getStoreConfig('path/to/field');

        $product->setName($product->getName() . $text);
    }
}
```